# Generating URIs in Jena for RDF

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, jena

I am generating an RDF file programmatically in Jena i.e. when I am inserting data in the rdf (instances) i need to have an unique URI (which will refer to the resource), somewhat like primary key in rdbms. I want to know is it posiible to do in Jena like when I will create Resource for an instance I can generate the URI ?

Example :

```
Resource resAnswer = ModelCreation.md.createResource(RDFResourcesURI.Answer_Resource_URI + answer.getAnswer_id());
```

-- here I am hardcoding (or user input) the answer_id and then appending to a predefined URI. Instead of hardcoding can I generate it (like auto increment in mysql ) ?

Comment: Related Question - http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/516/generating-unique-ids-in-triple-store-ala-mysql-auto_increment - Discussion on auto-incrementing IDs in Triple Stores in general

Answer (score 3):

There's a URI scheme for UUIDs http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt, so you can use that to turn UUIDs into URIs, e.g. e.g. urn:uuid:2238b240-f3eb-11e0-be50-0800200c9a66

Alternatively you can just append the UUID to some prefix, e.g. http://my.example/id/2238b240-f3eb-11e0-be50-0800200c9a66

HTTP based onetime URIs are good if you want to be able to make it resolvable.

Answer (score 1):

If you want just unique ID, you may use something like `UUID.randomUUID()` or `UUID.fromString(name)`

`UUID` is in `java.util` package

Answer (score 1):

I use `URN`'s for identifying my RDF resources as URL's add not much value since I'm not publishing my resources. There's a Jena library to generate `UUID` in the form of `URN`'s.

```
scala> import com.hp.hpl.jena.shared.uuid.JenaUUID
import com.hp.hpl.jena.shared.uuid.JenaUUID

scala> val resourceURN = JenaUUID.generate().asURN()
resourceURN: String = urn:uuid:0a9ac70c-2ad1-11b2-8012-10ddb1d60524
```